# Socket Event Listener(Titanium Studio Desktop)

Tags: javascript, jquery, sockets, titanium, appcelerator

I am building a desktop application using Titanium Studio and a slightly modified version of corMVC(http://www.bennadel.com/projects/cormvc-jquery-framework.htm) to structure the app as model-view-controller. The problem i am having is with the socket listening function. What i am trying to do is to use the same function that listens to the incoming data in different models, but every time i add a new listening function in a different model like this: `socket.onRead(readResponse);` it doesn't override the old function so when the server sends data to the client, it sends to all the functions registered with `socket.onRead`. Titanium desktop API also supports add and remove listeners on the socket but none of the listeners seem to work when receiving data, just the built-in onRead function. Is it possible to only listen to one function at a time?

What i tried so far:

1) Making a global function add the listener to it, then override it to every model. The override method seems to work when i call it, but when the server sends data it sends to the old non-override function.
2) Copy the socket variable to another variable and attach the listener to it, but this just attaches the listener to the original socket variable.
3) Tried to remove the current listening function in every way i could think of.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks